# TaskStackBuilder Android Version?

Tags: android, android-activity

Is this an error in the documentation or am I just not understanding this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html

It says it was `Added in API level 16` but then it says `Utility class for constructing synthetic back stacks for cross-task navigation on Android 3.0 and newer.` 3.0 is API 11.

I ask because I tried it on a device running 4.0.4 and couldn't figure out why I was getting a method not found error cause I thought it would work on 3.0 and up. Then i noticed it said added in api 16.

So whats up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android Support package has [a backport of `TaskStackBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html), for those who wish to build stacks of tasks on older API levels.

Comment: Older API levels meaning pre-16? How does one access the backport?

Comment: @bwoogie: "Older API levels meaning pre-16?" -- meaning API Level 4 onwards. "How does one access the backport?" -- it is in the Android Support package (a.k.a., Android Support library): http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html